# Prevent contextmenu on details list group headers in fluentui

Tags: reactjs, spfx, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a details list

```
  <DetailsList
          items={projects}
          columns={this.projectColumns}
          groups={projectGroups}
          selectionMode={SelectionMode.none}
          layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
          compact={isCompactMode}
          onItemContextMenu={this.onItemContextMenu}
        />
```

With my context menu functions:

```
 private onItemContextMenu = (item: any, index: number, ev: MouseEvent): boolean => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isContextMenuVisible: true,
      contextMenuTarget: {
        left: ev.clientX,
        top: ev.clientY,
      },
      selectedItem: item,
    });
    return false;
  };
  
  private hideContextMenu = (): void => {
    this.setState({ isContextMenuVisible: false, contextMenuTarget: null });
  };
  
  private deleteItem = (item: any): void => {
 console.log(item);
  };
```

How do I prevent clicking on group headers so that the user cannot open a context menu on it?

Answer (score 0):

In your column definitions you can add `columnActionsMode: ColumnActionsMode.disabled` to make the column header non-interactive.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    key: 'key',
    columnActionsMode: ColumnActionsMode.disabled
    ...
  },
  ... 
]
```

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem. The context menu still apears on group header.